# How can I make a website that takes GPIO input and runs programs on the server?

Tags: raspberry-pi, webserver

I got a Raspberry Pi the other day and thought it would be fun to set up a web server. I was wondering how I could make a website that took input, such as button clicks, and based on that input run a specific program/script.

I'm very new when it comes to programming, what would be the best approach to learn how to create a website / server?

Answer (score 0):

Andy your question is very vague so let me try to address it the best I can. You obviously seem new to this and that is great! However, questions like these are generally too broad to be answered.

First off, you seem very new to programming and if you are interested in creating a website I would recommend learning HTML. It isn't that complicated of a language and you can find tutorials on [Code Academy linked here.](https://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/htmlcss)

Second, if you are looking for help with button presses on a Raspberry Pi there are dozens of guides online [such as this one](http://raspberrywebserver.com/gpio/detecting-a-button-press-through-GPIO.html) to help you get on your way.

Finally, it seems you are very interested in running scripts and using a Raspberry Pi. One of the easiest languages to learn is called Python which is commonly used along side a Pi. It is a powerful language with tutorials on how to get started [here on Code Academy.](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/python)

What you are failing to realize is how powerful Google is, when you start programming you will realize how useful it really is. For the Raspberry Pi button push question, all you have to search is `raspberry pi detect button press`. The internet is your greatest resource to solving problems.

Good luck on all of your projects and don't forget that Google is your new best friend.

Comment: Did I answer your question or do you still need help?